# Invertibility of a linear combination of self-adjoint operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Assume a bounded linear operator $T:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{H},$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space, is invertible. Let $$A={1\over 2}(T+T^*),\quad B={1\over 2i}(T-T^*)$$ Does there exist   a real constant $r$ such that the operator $A+rB$ is injective ?

The operators $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint and $T=A+iB.$ The assumptions imply that $\ker A\cap \ker B=\{0\}.$
Assume  that $\ker (A-rB)\neq \{0\}$ for any positive value of $r.$ Let $0\neq x_r\in\ker (A-rB).$ Then for $s\neq r$ we get
$$\langle Ax_r,x_s\rangle =r\langle Bx_r,x_s\rangle,\quad \langle x_r,Ax_s\rangle =s\langle x_r,Bx_s\rangle$$
Therefore $$\langle Ax_r,x_s\rangle=0,\quad s\neq r$$

The conclusion is valid if one of the operators $A$ or $B$ is nonnegative. Indeed, consider the case $A\ge 0.$
Then
$$0=\langle Ax_r,x_s\rangle =\langle A^{1/2}x_r,A^{1/2}x_s\rangle \quad s\neq r$$
The family of nonzero orthogonal vectors $\{A^{1/2}x_r\}_{r>0}$ is uncountable, which leads to a contradiction.

The conclusion is valid also for any  normal invertible operator $T.$ In that case the operators $A$ and $B$ commute. We have $$\ker(A^2-r^2B^2)=\ker [(A+rB)(A-rB)]\supset \ker (A-rB)$$
The operator $A^2$ is nonnegative, hence there is $r\neq 0$ such that $\ker(A^2-r^2B^2)=\{0\}.$ Thus $A-rB$ is injective.

We cannot expect the invertibility of the operator $A+rB.$ I was able (spoiler) to get an example of an invertible operator $T$ such $A+rB$ is not invertible for any real value $r.$

> Let $\mathcal{H}=L^2(0,\pi)$ and $(Tf)(x)=e^{ix}f(x).$ Then $(Af)(x)=\cos x\,f(x) $ and $(Bf)(x)=\sin x\, f(x).$ Thus $[(A+rB)f](x)=(\cos x+r\sin x)\,f(x).$ The function $x\mapsto \cos x+r\sin x$ is not bounded away from $0,$ Therefore the operator $A+rB$ is not invertible.

Comment: The special case of multiplication operators on $L^2$ also seems to be an interesting question in its own right.

Comment: @NickAlger This case corresponds to commuting $A$ and $B.$

Comment: It seems to me that separability is essential. If you consider your example in $l^2(0,\pi)$ I think that $A+rB$ is never injective.

Comment: @Gerd That's right, as it suffices that the corresponding function vanishes at a point.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ahh yes that makes sense. Thanks for updating the post; I was thinking along these lines but couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: @NickAlger I was trying to deal with a normal operator $T$ or equivalently commuting $A$ and $B,$ with no success.

Comment: @NickAlger Eventually I have managed to solve the case of normal operator $T.$

Comment: @JacobManaker If $A$ and $B$ do not commute how do you know that $Av=Bv$ implies $A^2v=B^2v$ ? For this you need $ABv=BAv$ which is not guarranteed.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Ah, darn.  Sorry to get your hopes up.

Comment: @NickAlger Thanks for the investment!   HNY.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I'm now very curious to know the answer as well.

Comment: In the f.d. case, such $r$ are generic on the real line b/c they are roots of the determinant polynomial.  I can't find a way to generalize that fact to $B(\mathcal{H})$ — firstly, the Fuglede-Kadison determinant $\Delta(M)$ only detects whether $0\in\sigma(M)$ (i.e. $M$ is bounded below), not whether $M$ is injective; and secondly, the resulting function is only subharmonic, not meromorphic.

Comment: Since $A+iB$ is invertible, so must its adjoint $A-iB$ be; it thus suffices to show that $\{r:A+rB\text{ injective}\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ is connected, but I don't see an approach to the latter either.

Comment: Actually, for any $q\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm i\}$, there are $2\times2$ matrices $A,B$ of norm $\leq1$ such that $\exists(A+iB)^{-1}$ but $A+qB$ is not injective.  Taking $l^2$ sums, for any countable $Q\subseteq\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm i\}$, there are $A,B$ such that $\{r:A+rB\text{ injective}\}\cap Q=\emptyset$.  In particular, $Q$ can be dense in $\mathbb{C}$, which really nails the determinant idea into the coffin.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Oh, absolutely; I didn't mean to suggest I had a counterexample, because in fact I think your conjecture is true.  I'm just trying to summarize some failed approaches and obstructions in case they help another reader.

Comment: @JacobManaker I get your intensions, and appreciate your construction. I do hope you come up with a proof of the conjecture. I have impression that it is around the corner, but I cannot see it.

Comment: @JacobManaker The bounty expires tomorrow. Could you write up an answer summarizing the situation and failed approaches? Then (assuming no one else figures it out in the meantime) I can award the bounty to your answer so it won't go to waste. Also the answer will be useful for future people who find this question.

Comment: @NickAlger Sure; thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Not a solution, but a summary of partial progress, failed approaches, and sharpness tests.

- The claim is known (from the OP) if $[A,B]=0$, if $A\geq0$, or if $B\geq0$.
- The claim is also known if $0\notin\sigma(A)\cup\sigma(B)$.

  For example, if $0\notin\sigma(B)$, then there exists $m$ such that $\|Bv\|\geq m\|v\|$ for all $v\in\mathcal{H}$.  Thus if $r\geq(1+\epsilon)\frac{\|A\|}{m}$, then for all $v\in\mathcal{H}$ \begin{align*}
  \|(A+rB)v\|&\geq r\|Bv\|-\|Av\|\\
  &\geq(1+\epsilon)\frac{\|A\|}{m}\cdot m\|v\|-\|A\|\cdot\|v\|\\
  &=\epsilon\|A\|\cdot\|v\|
  \end{align*}  Thus $A+rB$ is injective.
- Unfortunately, there are circumstances in which $0\in\sigma(A)\cap\sigma(B)$.  For example, the multiplication operator mentioned behind the spoiler in the OP is of this form.
- The claim is false for inseparable Hilbert spaces; the OP's spoiler provides a counter-example.
- The claim is, however, true if $\mathcal{H}$ is finite-dimensional.

  Let $f(r)=\det(A+rB)$, so that $f(r)=0$ iff $A+rB$ is injective.  The map $f(r)\in\mathbb{R}[r]$ and has a holomorphic extension to $\mathbb{C}$; by the previous sentence, $f(i)\neq0$; and so the holomorphic extension $f\neq0$.  But nonzero holomorphic functions have isolated roots, so that $f(r)\neq0$ for generic $r$.
- Generalizing the previous point to $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ faces substantial obstacles.

  First, one loses holomorphism.  In $n$ dimensions, $\det(2)=2^n$.  For a finite value in arbitrary dimensions, one must use the normalized determinant $\sqrt[n]{|\det|}$; but the latter function is only subharmonic.  In general, subharmonic functions can accumulate roots.  For example, $z\mapsto\max(0,\log(|z|))$ on $\mathbb{C}$ is subharmonic, but vanishes on $\mathbb{D}$.

  Worse, the most relevant infinite-dimensional determinant I know is the Fuglede-Kadison determinant $$\Delta(M)=e^{\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(\log(M^*M))}$$ which is well-defined as long as $0\notin\sigma(M)$ and has a continuous extension vanishing iff $0\in\sigma(M)$.  Thus $\Delta(A+rB)$ only detects whether $0\in\sigma(A+rB)$, not whether $A+rB$ is injective.
- Nevertheless, one might investigate the set $R=\{r:A+rB\text{ injective}\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, hoping to show that $R\cap\mathbb{R}\neq\emptyset$.  On the one hand, $R$ is closed under complex conjugation: an operator is invertible iff its adjoint is, and $$(A+rB)^*=A+\overline{r}B$$
- On the other hand, for any countable $Q\subseteq\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\pm i\}$, I think there is a choice of $T$ such that $R\cap Q=\emptyset$.  (My original construction of $T$ has a technical flaw, but can almost certainly be repaired; I sketch the argument below behind a spoiler.)

  Fix $0<l<u<\infty$ to be determined later and enumerate $Q$ as $\{q_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$.  For each $n$, I claim (see spoilered section below) that there are self-adjoint $A_n,B_n\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ such that $A_n+iB_n$ is invertible with $\|A_n+iB_n\|<\sqrt{u}$ and $\|(A_n+iB_n)^{-1}\|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{l}}$, but $A_n+q_nB_n$ has nontrivial kernel.

  Now let $H=\bigoplus_n{\mathbb{C}^2}$ and let $\mathcal{H}$ be the completion of $H$ under the $l^2$ norm.  Let $T$ act block-diagonally on $H$, with each block $A_n+iB_n$; then $T$ extends to $\mathcal{H}$ by continuity with $\|T\|\leq\sqrt{u}$ and $\|T^{-1}\|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{l}}$.  The associated operators $A$, $B$, and $T^{-1}$ are similarly block-diagonal: each block of $A$ is $A_n$, etc.  But for any $q_n$ there is a $v\in\mathcal{H}$ such that $$(A+q_nB)v=(A_n+q_nB_n)v=0$$  Thus $q_n\notin R$.

  > ! To construct such $A_n$ and $B_n$, let the two eigenvalues of $A_n+iB_n$ be $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.  Then we seek $A_n,B_n$ self-adjoint with \begin{gather*}
  > \det(A_n+q_nB_n)=0 \\
  > \sqrt{l}<|\lambda_2|\leq|\lambda_1|<\sqrt{u}
  > \end{gather*}  To address the eigenvalue condition, it suffices to instead work with \begin{alignat*}{3}
  > &d=&|\det(A_n+iB_n)|^2&=|\lambda_1|^2|\lambda_2|^2\\
  > &n=&\|A_n+iB_n\|_F^2&=|\lambda_1|^2+|\lambda_2|^2
  > \end{alignat*} by Vieta's formulas.  In the latter language, we require \begin{gather*}
  > \det(A_n+q_nB_n)=0 \\
  > 2l<n<2u \\
  > 2l(n-2l)<4d<n^2
  > \end{gather*}
  > !
  > ! I originally thought I had an explicit solution to these conditions, because I forgot about the lower bound $l$, which it violates.  Nevertheless, the space of pairs of self-adjoint matrices is $8$-dimensional (over $\mathbb{R}$), and there are three conditions here, polynomial in the matrix entries (two quadratic and one quartic).  In principle there should be a $5$-dimensional moduli space of solutions.
  > !
  > ! The only tricky condition is the last line, because if $q_n\approx\pm i$, then we should expect $d\approx0$ as well.  But although the last condition forces $d\neq0$, it does allow $d$ to be arbitrarily small — just choose $n\approx 2l$.
  > !
  > ! Readers skeptical that the moduli space is nonempty are invited to investigate further.
- Even in the previous point, the possibility remains that $R$ is (path-)connected.  Because $\{\pm i\}\subseteq R$, if $R$ is (path-)connected, then it must intersect $\mathbb{R}$.  But there is no clear reason why $R$ should exhibit either property.
- Likewise for full measure or comeagerity.
- The claim is false if the requirement that $\exists(A+Bi)^{-1}$ is weakened to $\ker(A)\cap\ker(B)=0$.  Indeed, let $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{C}^3$; $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\quad\quad\text{ and }\quad\quad B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$  Then $\ker(A)=\mathbb{C}(0,0,1)$ and $\ker(B)=\mathbb{C}(0,1,0)$, but $\det(A+rB)=0$ for any $r$.
- The claim also appears to hold if $A$ and $B$ are allowed to be unbounded.  For example, let $A=x$ and $B=i\frac{d}{dx}$ on $L^2$.  Then solutions to $(A+rB)f=0$ are oscillatory, whereas solutions to $(A+iB)f=0$ grow or decay without bound.  Thus if we attempt to tweak $L^2$ to make $A+rB$ not injective, then we will almost certainly be forced to include function-classes that make $A+iB$ not injective (and thus not invertible).

Comment: Wow, thanks for your contribution. I am impressed by the amount and the quality of the analysis. (+).

Comment: I will be happy to accept your answer, say, two hours before the deadline. Let's see if someone else is going to contribute until then.

Comment: Thanks for writing up this summary! I awarded the bounty. At this point perhaps it would be useful to cross post on mathoverflow